# Power calculation for multiple level clustering / randomization using simulations R

Tags: clustering, simulation, statistical-power, hierarchical-clustering, cluster-sample

I am trying to calculate power of the following design:

-Treatment is randomized over a small number of clusters (1st level clustering=regions)

-Within each region we randomly select villages (second level clustering)

-Within each village we randomly select individuals

-Outcome is the % of **individuals** using service X in the whole sample (individual level binary outcome)

Since the number of first level clusters (regions) is very low (<20), I am using simulations for power calculations using the clusterPower package. But I don't know how to account for the multiple level of clustering within my code. 
Is there a way to account for both low cluster number and the multiple level of randomization on R?  We're basically trying to figure out how many villages to sample within a region, and how many individuals within a village.

This is my first time using R so I'd really appreciate any help on this!!

Comment: You need to specify how large each effect is & the ICC at each level, etc. Are you just asking for code?